# FFMPEG - how to transpose only if image is portrait

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to transpose images ***only*** if portrait is detected.

Let's say you took a picture using your cellphone in portrait mode:
it could be 960 x 1280. In that case, I need it to be rotated 90 degrees so when opening in desktop it is 1280 x 960.

What should be the ffmpeg command?

PS: it is also an acceptable solution if it works for picture.height > picture.width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transpose filter has an option for this:

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf transpose=clock:passthrough=landscape out
```

This will rotate only portrait input 90 deg clockwise.

See all available values at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose-1

Comment: thank you very much! it is exactly what i needed